# JPanel doesn't adapt to any changes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

At first, I called my panel inside my JFrame. Everything worked just fine.

Now I wanted to call the panel from another class to switch to different panels within the same JFrame after choosing one of them. The problem that occurred to me is the following:

> The JFrame does not respond in any way to changes I set to the panel. Neither when e.g. resizing it inside the Panel class nor when resizing it in the JFrame class.

The panel always expands the same size as the JFrame like a Flowlayout. But trying to change the layout didn't work either nor should it matter in any way since the Panel worked before (when coded inside the JFrame and not in a separate class).

How do I fix the code in that way, that I can adjust the panel and make the JFrame recognize those changes? I am currently using Eclipse and NetBeans; doesn't work in either one.

**Main:**

```
package calculatorXtreme;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface interface1 =new Interface();
        interface1.show();
    }

}
```

**Panel:**

```
package calculatorXtreme;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PannelDez extends JPanel {
    JLabel text = new JLabel();
    JButton delete = new JButton();
    JButton zero = new JButton();
    JButton eins = new JButton();
    JButton zwei = new JButton();
    JButton drei = new JButton();
    JButton vier = new JButton();
    JButton fuenf = new JButton();
    JButton sechs = new JButton();
    JButton sieben = new JButton();
    JButton acht = new JButton();
    JButton neun = new JButton();
    JButton addieren = new JButton();
    JButton subtrahieren = new JButton();
    JButton multiplizieren = new JButton();
    JButton dividieren = new JButton();
    JButton ergebnis = new JButton();
    JTextField anzeige = new JTextField();
    String erg = "";
    int temp1;
    RechnerInt interfaceRechner = new RechnerInt();

    public PannelDez() {

        //Panel

        this.setSize(400, 500);
        anzeige.setBounds(125,100, 200, 50);
        anzeige.setSize(200, 50);
        anzeige.setEditable(false);
        anzeige.setText(erg);
        this.add(anzeige);


        //Buttons 

        delete.setText("C");
        zero.setText("0");
        eins.setText("1");
        zwei.setText("2");
        drei.setText("3");
        vier.setText("4");
        fuenf.setText("5");
        sechs.setText("6");
        sieben.setText("7");
        acht.setText("8");
        neun.setText("9");
        addieren.setText("+");
        subtrahieren.setText("-");
        multiplizieren.setText("*");
        dividieren.setText("/");
        ergebnis.setText("=");



        this.add(delete);
        this.add(zero);
        this.add(eins);
        this.add(zwei);
        this.add(drei);
        this.add(vier);
        this.add(fuenf);
        this.add(sechs);
        this.add(sieben);
        this.add(acht);
        this.add(neun);
        this.add(addieren);
        this.add(subtrahieren);
        this.add(multiplizieren);
        this.add(dividieren);
        this.add(ergebnis);

        delete.addActionListener(new ListenDelete());
        zero.addActionListener(new ListenZero());
        eins.addActionListener(new ListenEins());
        zwei.addActionListener(new ListenZwei());
        drei.addActionListener(new ListenDrei());
        vier.addActionListener(new ListenVier());
        fuenf.addActionListener(new ListenFuenf());
        sechs.addActionListener(new ListenSechs());
        sieben.addActionListener(new ListenSieben());
        acht.addActionListener(new ListenAcht());
        neun.addActionListener(new ListenNeun());
        addieren.addActionListener(new ListenAddieren());
        subtrahieren.addActionListener(new ListenSubtrahieren());
        multiplizieren.addActionListener(new ListenMultiplizieren());
        dividieren.addActionListener(new ListenDividieren());
        ergebnis.addActionListener(new ListenErgebnis());

        /* JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  */

    }

    public void resizeButtons()
    {
        delete.setBounds(225, 350, 50, 50);
        zero.setBounds(175, 350,50,50);
        eins.setBounds(125, 300,50,50);
        zwei.setBounds(175, 300,50,50);
        drei.setBounds(225, 300,50,50);
        vier.setBounds(125, 250,50,50);
        fuenf.setBounds(175, 250,50,50);
        sechs.setBounds(225, 250,50,50);
        sieben.setBounds(125, 200,50,50);
        acht.setBounds(175, 200,50,50);
        neun.setBounds(225, 200,50,50);
        addieren.setBounds(275, 300,50,50);
        subtrahieren.setBounds(275, 250,50,50);
        multiplizieren.setBounds(275, 200,50,50);
        dividieren.setBounds(275, 150,50,50);
        ergebnis.setBounds(275, 350,50,50);
    }

    class ListenDelete implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            interfaceRechner.operators.clear();
            interfaceRechner.numbers.clear();
            interfaceRechner.numbersInt.clear();
            anzeige.setText("");
        }
    }
    class ListenZero implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "0");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenEins implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "1");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            return;
        }
    }
    class ListenZwei implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "2");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenDrei implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "3");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenVier implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "4");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenFuenf implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "5");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenSechs implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "6");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenSieben implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "7");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenAcht implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "8");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenNeun implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            anzeige.setText(erg + "9");
            erg = anzeige.getText();
        }
    }
    class ListenAddieren implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            erg = anzeige.getText();
            interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(erg));
            interfaceRechner.addOperators("+");
            anzeige.setText("");
            erg = null;
        }
    }
    class ListenSubtrahieren implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                erg = anzeige.getText();
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(erg));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("-");
                anzeige.setText("");
                erg = null;
            }
        }
    class ListenMultiplizieren implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                erg = anzeige.getText();
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(erg));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("*");
                anzeige.setText("");
                erg = null;
            }
        }
    class ListenDividieren implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                erg = anzeige.getText();
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(erg));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("/");
                anzeige.setText("");
                erg = null;
            }
        }
    class ListenErgebnis implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                erg = anzeige.getText();
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(erg));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("=");
                anzeige.setText(""+interfaceRechner.berechneInt());

            }
        }

}
```

**JFrame:**

```
package calculatorXtreme;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class Interface extends JFrame  {

public Interface(){

// PanelAdden

PannelDez panel2 = new PannelDez();
//panel2.setSize(400, 500);
this.setSize(700, 800);
panel2.setSize(300, 200);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);
panel2.setSize(400, 500);
panel2.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 500);
panel2.resizeButtons();
this.add(panel2);

// Menüleiste

JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
this.setJMenuBar(jmb);
JMenu file = new JMenu("Option");
jmb.add(file);
JMenuItem dez = new JMenuItem("Dezimal-Rechner");
file.add(dez);
JMenuItem hex = new JMenuItem("Hex-Rechner");
file.add(hex);
this.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

**RechnerInt:**

```
package calculatorXtreme;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RechnerInt {
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> numbersDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> numbersInt = new ArrayList<>();
    double zahl1, zahl2, ergebnis;
    String op;
    boolean abbruch = true;

    public double rechnen(String op, double zahl1, double zahl2)

    {

        switch (op) {
        case "+":
            ergebnis = zahl1 + zahl2;
            return ergebnis;
        case "-":
            ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;
            return ergebnis;
        case "/":
            ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2;
            return ergebnis;
        case "*":
            ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;
            return ergebnis;
        }
        return ergebnis;
    }

    public double meineNemesis() {

        zahl1 = numbersDouble.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= numbersDouble.size(); i++)

        {
            op = operators.get(i - 1);

            if (op.equals("=")) {
                return zahl1;
            }
            zahl2 = numbersDouble.get(i);
            zahl1 = rechnen(op, zahl1, zahl2);
        }
        return -80085;
    }

    public int berechneInt() 
    {
        zahl1 = numbersInt.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= numbersInt.size(); i++)

        {
            op = operators.get(i - 1);

            if (op.equals("=")) {
                return (int)zahl1;
            }
            zahl2 = numbersInt.get(i);
            zahl1 = rechnen(op, zahl1, zahl2);
        }
        return -80085 ;
    }


    public void addNumber(int i) 
    {
        numbersInt.add(i);
    }

    public void addOperators(String op)
    {
        operators.add(op);
        }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is this `RechnerInt` class? where is the code for this class, and how does it relate to your code above? Where does your code try to make changes to the GUI? Please clarify your code explanation and your problem.

Comment: Side issue: While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: To summarize HFOE’s point:  remove all of your calls to `setBounds`, and [learn to use layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) instead.  Layout managers literally exist to address your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels - Addet RechnerInt class. I do try to change the panel size with "panel2.setSize" or "this.setSize" depending on the location. I tried various methods but deleted them in this code for readability.

Comment: @VGR - Thank you for your contribution. I'll try to use the suggested layout managers in the future. Yet I would like to know why in this case, neither a manager (I tried to change the layout) nor any change in size or color is admitted by my JFrame. Neither when changing attributes directly in the panel class nor when changing it in JFrame.

Comment: From the [JFrame documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html): “The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it.”  `this.add(panel2)` makes panel2 the center child of a BorderLayout, so panel2 will always stretch to fill the frame.

Comment: @VGR - As stated, the JPanel worked perfectly fine while being used inside the same class as the JFrame. I was able to adjust the location of the buttons without using any layout. Only when calling it from another class it messes up. I will try your solution anyhow of course - please consider submitting this as an answer so I am able to give due credit when needed.

Comment: I don’t want to answer until I’m sure of the problem.  I was under the impression that no code was attempting to change the size of the panel, until you wrote another class that tried to change it.  Is that correct?

Comment: @VGR - At first I had the class "Interface" which extended from JFrame. In this class I created a JPanel, adjusted it to my liking and it worked fine. Then I created another class, called "PannelDez". I removed the JPanel from "Interface" and put it into "PannelDez" which extended from JPanel. There I created my panel. When I was calling it from my "Interface" class, I was able to call, but all the adjustments regarding size etc. are not transfering. When trying to change attributes in "Interface" it's not working either. The panel just uses its standard formats and fits to the JFrame.

Comment: Why are you not using a CardLayout to simplify swapping of components? The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels - I am sure that here are a hundred more intelligent ways then what I have to do here. But aside from that, I like to know why inside my Class "Interface" the command "// panel2.setSize(400, 500)" is being ignored. Please notice, that it's only here "//" because I tried different approaches. And when I type in the command "this.setSize(400, 500);" in the class "PannelDez" it's getting ignored aswell. I can't adjust the size to another then my JFrame. But I was able to earlier, when I had the JPanel inside the same class as my JFrame.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Thanks for that information; I'll keep it in mind though it's not working here. Maybe it's a problem with my compiler (though I sincerely doubt that). And you are very much right regarding the canonical solution. I'll present what I'm able to do with the method that my mentor showed me while trying to prepare another solution using your suggested CardLayout. Thank you very much for you patience and knowledge.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your compiler, guaranteed

Comment: And if you're using `setBounds(...)` you need to use a `null` layout in the JFrame. Something I neither recommend nor use often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from not setting the layouts of *both* your JFrame and the JPanel to `null`, so that the `setBounds(...)` would take effect. Without setting the layout explicitly in this way, the JPanel will blindly use its default FlowLayout, and the JFrame (actually its contentPane) will blindly use its default BorderLayout

So these changes are needed:

```
class PannelDez extends JPanel {
    // .....

    public PannelDez() {
        // Panel
        setLayout(null);

        // ....
    }

    // ....
}
```

```
class Interface extends JFrame {

    public Interface() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        // PanelAdden

        // .....

    }

    // ..........

}
```

But having said that, I reiterate what I've stated before:

> While null layouts and setBounds() might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

And again that the better way to solve this is to learn and use layout managers. For example, you're creating a calculator, and this lends itself well to use of two JPanels, one to hold the buttons that uses a GridLayout so as to create a grid of buttons, and the other using a BorderLayout to hold the above JPanel in its center position, and to hold your JTextField in the top position, the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` position.  Also note that best to try to avoid code duplication such as we see in all your ActionListeners.  You only need *two* ActionListeners -- one for each number button and one for each operation.

The code below creates a Swing GUI as described above, one with nested JPanels, the outer one using BorderLayout and the inner using GridLayout(0, 4), which stands for variable number of rows (the 0), and 4 columns. An image of the GUI:

[image]

And the code:

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FooGui02 extends JPanel {
    private static final Font BUTTON_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 36);
    private static final Font ANZEIGE_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 24);
    private JTextField anzeige = new JTextField(10);
    RechnerInt interfaceRechner = new RechnerInt();

    public FooGui02() {
        anzeige.setFont(ANZEIGE_FONT);
        // anzeige.setEnabled(false);
        anzeige.setBackground(null);
        anzeige.setFocusable(false); // user can't interact with this

        // create a grid of 4 columns and variable rows:
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4));

        // create first row
        // add 3 blank JLabels
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            btnPanel.add(new JLabel());
        }
        btnPanel.add(createOperationButton(Operation.DIVISION));

        // second row
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(7));
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(8));
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(9));
        btnPanel.add(createOperationButton(Operation.MULTIPLICATION));

        // third row
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(4));
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(5));
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(6));
        btnPanel.add(createOperationButton(Operation.SUBTRACTION));

        // forth row
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(1));
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(2));
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(3));
        btnPanel.add(createOperationButton(Operation.ADDITION));

        // fifth row
        btnPanel.add(new JLabel());
        btnPanel.add(createNumberButton(0));
        btnPanel.add(createOperationButton(Operation.CLEAR));
        btnPanel.add(createOperationButton(Operation.EQUALS));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(anzeige, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(btnPanel);
    }

    private JButton createOperationButton(Operation operation) {
        JButton button = new JButton(operation.getText());
        button.addActionListener(new OperationListener(operation));
        button.setFont(BUTTON_FONT);
        return button;
    }

    private JButton createNumberButton(int number) {
        JButton button = new JButton("" + number);
        button.addActionListener(new NumberListener(number));
        button.setFont(BUTTON_FONT);
        return button;
    }

    private class OperationListener implements ActionListener {
        private Operation operation;

        public OperationListener(Operation operation) {
            this.operation = operation;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = anzeige.getText();

            switch (operation) {
            case CLEAR:
                interfaceRechner.operators.clear();
                interfaceRechner.numbers.clear();
                interfaceRechner.numbersInt.clear();
                anzeige.setText("");
                break;

            case ADDITION:
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(text));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("+");
                anzeige.setText("");
                break;

            case SUBTRACTION:
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(text));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("-");
                anzeige.setText("");
                break;

            case MULTIPLICATION:
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(text));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("*");
                anzeige.setText("");
                break;

            case DIVISION:
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(text));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("/");
                anzeige.setText("");
                break;

            case EQUALS:
                interfaceRechner.addNumber(Integer.valueOf(text));
                interfaceRechner.addOperators("=");
                anzeige.setText("" + interfaceRechner.berechneInt());
                interfaceRechner.operators.clear();
                interfaceRechner.numbers.clear();
                interfaceRechner.numbersInt.clear();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class NumberListener implements ActionListener {
        private int number;

        public NumberListener(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = anzeige.getText();
            text += number;
            anzeige.setText(text);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        FooGui02 mainPanel = new FooGui02();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
enum Operation {
    DIVISION("/"), MULTIPLICATION("*"), SUBTRACTION("-"), 
    ADDITION("+"), CLEAR("C"), EQUALS("=");

    private String text;

    private Operation(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```